# What effect has "+:ALL:cron crond" in /etc/security/access.conf?

Tags: security, cron, pam, access-control

I am refining our rules in /etc/securiy/access.conf. I found the following rule and I am not sure what it is used for:

```
+:ALL:cron crond
```

According to the man page of access.conf it means something like:
*Grant permission to ALL users from origin cron and crond.*

I do not understand what it means in detail. Can someone provide an example where this rule would take in effect.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Cronjobs are run with a certain user.
This line allows cron/crond to run the jobs as all users.
You can read more about that [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/crond)

I hope this helps